Primefaces native upload not working with PrettyFaces (OCPSoft Rewrite)
I need to migrate my application to Jakarta EE 10, and here are my current configurations:

JDK 1.8
Primefaces 12.0.x
PrettyFaces 3.3.3

I have updated my pom.xml with the new dependencies, replacing PrettyFaces with OCPSoft Rewrite, as the version is not compatible with Jakarta.
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source>21</java.source>
        <java.target>21</java.target>
        <rewrite.version>10.0.2.Final</rewrite.version>
        <jakarta.version>10.0.0</jakarta.version>
        <primefaces.version>14.0.4</primefaces.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${rewrite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
            <version>${rewrite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I haven't modified my beans, the @URLMapping annotations remain unchanged and work correctly; however, file upload no longer works because PrettyFaces (OCPSoft Rewrite) intercepts the call and thus doesn't propagate it to the bean. I can't use Apache Commons because it's not compatible with the Jakarta version, so I need to use the native upload:
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
</context-param>

One solution is to add this JavaScript and modify the form’s action, but it’s a solution that forces me to review all the pages.
"$("form").attr("action", "#{request.contextPath}/example.xhtml")"
Has anyone encountered this issue before?

I have created a global javascript function:
var initMultiparts = function(url) {
  $("form").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('action', url);
  });
};

In my template.xhtml, I call this function and passing request URL:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    JavascriptApp.initMultiparts('#{request.requestURL}');
  });
</script>

